# Http post request Android not working

Tags: android, http, post, httpurlconnection

Hello guys I am new in Android development and I am trying to implement a HTTP POST connection in Android using URLConnection, but my function returns nothing from server and I don't know what is wrong in my code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public String sendHttpRequest() throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{

    String name = null;
    String pwd = null;
    name = user_name.getText().toString();
    pwd = password.getText().toString();


    String text = " ";
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL("example.com");

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        String s = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
        s += "&" +  URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pwd, "UTF-8");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        Log.i("show1",wr.getEncoding().toString());
        wr.write(s);
        wr.flush();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        text = sb.toString();





    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
    Log.i("show", text);
    Log.d("data",text);

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return text;
}
```

Comment: Crashlog or stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing:

```
 urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: did try that but no result.